# Where can Qt Creator plugins in binary form be found?

Tags: qt, plugins, ide, qt4, qt-creator

Where can I find plugins for [Qt Creator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_Creator) available in binary form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the diversity of platforms that Qt supports you may be hard pressed to find many plugins in binary form. The Qt developer network does maintain a list of [QtCreator plugins here](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/Qt_Creator_Plug-in_Gallery). Some of these may be available in binary formats but since they are plugins for software designed to compile software, it shouldn't be a big problem if you have to build them yourself :)

Comment: Typically do i have to compile to whole IDE or just the plugin ?

Comment: You should only have to compile the plugin. That's one of the advantages of the plugin model. Another is the ability to load or change plugins without having to restart the host application. I've never used QtCreator plugins myself so the particulars may vary.

Comment: Can I compile plugins in/using QtCreator ? :)

Comment: As long as the plugin you want to compile has a .pro or Qt project file you should be able to open it and build it with QtCreator. Although a .pro file is not technically required, it would be quite unusual if a plugin with source didn't have one.

Comment: Ok and can I compile those plugins for windows in default qtcreator and use them in default qtcreator ? I heard that qtcreator supplied by nokia is build in VS.

Comment: My operative word up until now has been "should". You won't really know until you try it :)